# Array Element is a Variable in Array of Strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to initialize an array of strings in C. I want to set one of the elements of the array from a variable, but I'm getting a compiler error. What's wrong with this?

```
char * const APP_NAME = "test_app";

char * const array_of_strings[4] = {
    APP_NAME,
    "-f", "/path/to/file.txt",
    NULL
};
```

The error is `error: initializer element is not constant`.

Comment: maybe try 'const * const, so 'const * const APP_NAME'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard distinguishes `const`-qualified variables and compile time constants.

Evaluating a variable (`APP_NAME`) is not considered to be a compile time constant in the sense of the C standard. This

```
char const app_name[] = "test_app";

char const*const array_of_strings[4] = {
    &app_name[0],
    "-f", "/path/to/file.txt",
    0,
};
```

would be allowed, since this is not evaluating `app_name` but only taking its address.

Also, you always should treat string literals as if they had type `char const[]`. Modifying them has undefined behavior, so you should protect yourself from doing so.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this but I get `warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to compile with this syntax using gcc 4.6.3:

```
char* const APP_NAME = "test_app";
char* const array_of_strings[4] = {
    APP_NAME,
    "-f", "/path/to/file.txt",
    NULL
};
```

You could also try casting to a const (at your own risk) if the compiler rejects everything else:

```
char* const APP_NAME = "test_app";
char* const array_of_strings[4] = {
    (char* const)APP_NAME,
    "-f", "/path/to/file.txt",
    NULL
};
```