# Make an array of arrays of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have arrays of strings. I want to put these arrays into an array. How can I do so? I have tried this:

```
char const * const fruits[3] = {
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "orange",
};

char const * const colors[3] = {
    "red",
    "green",
    "blue",
};

char * preset_configurations[3] =
{
    NULL, /* leave the first one blank so that this list is 1-based */
    &fruits,
    &colors,
};
```

but I get `warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type`. Any idea?

Comment: Don't put the ampersand in front of fruits and colors. Since they are arrays, they will be interpreted as pointers to their first elements in that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a double pointer and some consts (as well as getting rid of the ampersands) :

```
char const * const * preset_configurations[3] =
{
    NULL, /* leave the first one blank so that this list is 1-based */
    fruits,
    colors
};
```

EDIT: I suppose, given the extra information after I posted the above, that the best solution to your problem is:

```
// This will copy the characters of the words into the 3 16-byte arrays.
char fruits[3][16] = {
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "orange"
};
// Ditto.
char colors[3][16] = {
    "red",
    "green",
    "blue"
};
// This is how to point to the above.
char (*preset_configurations[3])[16] = {
    NULL, // this list is 1-based
    fruits,
    colors,
};
```

That way the strings are no longer constant strings (which, as you said, the exec functions don't want).

Comment: const preservation FTW!

Comment: Is it possible for me to have `preset_configurations` be a `char * const*`? I am trying to pass it to the linux `execv` function which requires `char * const*`.

Comment: Just remove the first const from all of them. Although, technically, you should have `char const` since you're pointing to string constants.

Comment: @ooga note, that will flag at least a compiler warning for deprecation since the literal is const by nature. Most C-compilers will allow it regardless unless some pretty pedantic warnings are being used. Ex: clang will report: "Initializing `'char *const *'` with an expression of type `'const char *const [3]'` discards qualifiers in nested pointer types."

Comment: Right, I should have said "use actual char arrays and initialize them with your strings".

Comment: Hmmm.. I think I got it. I had the const's that way because of my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491713/array-element-is-a-variable-in-array-of-strings-in-c/21491928

Comment: Can you explain a little about what's going on? I am new to C and hate asking these dumb questions. I would like to understand better `const * const *` and arrays, etc...

Comment: @unexpected62 ensconced within [this answer to a somewhat related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562845/why-does-passing-char-as-const-char-generate-a-warning/14566215#14566215) is a diatribe on every conceivable meaning of `const` and `*` through double-indirection (i.e. pointers to pointers). It may help you understand better.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef const char const *(*cp3)[3];
cp3 preset_configurations[3] = {
    NULL,
    &fruits,
    &colors,
};
//printf("%s\n", (*preset_configurations[1])[2]);//orange
```